# Showing alert box repeatedly on closing colorbox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, colorbox

I have added `colorbox` to my app. I have overridden the close functionality

```
$('#cboxClose').on('click',function(){
        alert('message');
        parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
        return false;

    });
```

But when i am closing `colorbox` it is showing me multiple alertbox(the number of time i have opened the `colorbox`).

Any guess?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For **jQuery 1.7** and before
Use:

```
$('#cboxClose').unbind('click').on('click',function(){
    alert('message');
    parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
    return false;
});
```

For libraries after **jQuery 1.7**

```
$('#cboxClose').off('click').on('click',function(){
    alert('message');
    parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: With jQuery 1.7 onward the event API has been updated to use .on/off rather than .bind/.unbind off course for backward compatibility they still can be used.

Answer (score 1):

you need to first off the event cause otherwise it fires multiple times:

```
$('#cboxClose').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('message');
        parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add the below code before your `on` statement

```
$('#cboxClose').off('click');
```